# Passing function variable through database

Tags: ajax, database, variables

Is it possible to fill in a variable through database for a function?

The file that follows is called from an ajax request through a function to display in a div on my index page.

the file is as follows:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tagID, views FROM tbl_favorites");

$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($count == 0){
    echo "Error to display!";
}
else{
    $arrayViews = array();
    while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $arrayViews[] = $results['views'];
    }
}
$max = max($arrayViews);
rsort($arrayViews);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    $favoriteQuery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tagID FROM tbl_favorites WHERE views = '".$arrayViews[$i]."'");
    while ($favorite = mysqli_fetch_array($favoriteQuery)){ 
        echo "<a class='favoriteKeyword' onclick='fetchResult(".$favorite['tagID'].", null);' href=><p id='key'>".$favorite['tagID']."</p></a>";
    }
}

//close connection after query executes
mysqli_close($con);
```

?>
This is actually being populated successfully, but when using the function in a `onClick = functionName` (PHP value retrieve from database), it doesn't work. Why does this happen?

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear at all what you are asking?

Comment: I have an HTML file requesting for a php file in an ajax function..the php file contain a tag <button> where an onClick is applied and then calling the function by passing the values of the variable from the database;...in debug it appears correctly but when I clicks the button no action is made...is it clearer please?

Comment: please edit your question

Comment: Hope the changes made could help...Thank you in advance